# how to update all the reference and target and hintPath 's version in a.csproj file while installing a .nuget in a.net standard app?

Tags: xml, .net-standard, nuspec, msbuild-target

currently my .csproj contain these peace of code

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Sip5-SI" Version="4.0.10" />
 <ItemGroup>
 <Target Name="CopyReferenceDll" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="..\..\_Common\packages\Sip5-SI.4.0.10\lib\netstandard2.0\Wrapper.dll" DestinationFolder="$(TargetDir)" />


</Target>
```

when I update the SIP5-SI package only `PackageReference` getting updated not the `Target`, `Copy` what are the changes I need to do in `SIP5-SI` nuspec file to solve this issue